# Satchmo's Contact Form Dont send email

Tags: python, django, contacts, django-registration, satchmo

I am a newbie using satchmo shop for the first time. This is my first ever question with stack too. So far I have been able to manage the customization to a reasonably well except the 2 things that I am eagerly looking to work for me.

1. When try to send an email through Contact form, emails are not sent??
2. Can anyone give me pointer/guide for a working setting in order to test and run django-registration for my new shop??

Comment: EMAIL_HOST = 'asia.secureserver.net'  # Usually set to localhost  <br/>
EMAIL_PORT = 587  <br/>
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@domain.com'  <br/>
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'gulam'  <br/>
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True  <br/> Above is the email setting that I filled in my local_setting.py which I am sure is wrong. <br/> The point is I need to enable my Contact form to work (I should be able to recv emails from the visitors) <br /> When I fill in Contact form and click on send, it gives me no error. <br /> How am I suppose to configure it?? This was my 1st question. <br /> Regds.

Comment: if there is problem in email settings then try this one, `EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

 EMAIL_PORT = 587

 EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myname@gmail.com'

 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` this works for me!

Comment: Oh..wow that really works for me too. I am thrilled to recv that email. thanks

Comment: I would be highly obliged if I could also recv an answer for my 2nd question. How can I check django-registration in my setup? What are the possible steps  that I need to take in order to make it work?

Comment: As your question title, its resolved now, so i would recommend you make an another question for registration, then you will get quick response.

Answer (score 1):

if there is problem in email settings then try this one,

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myname@gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

this works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess this steps would help:

- make sure you have 'registration' on your INSTALLED_APPS on the settings.py
- you must set the LIVESETTINGS_OPTIONS to. This can be done from the Livesettings-app in the Admin while not on Pruduction. Afterwards you should make sure you turn them off with the 'DB'-option turned to False and "hardcoding" your live-settings on settings.py (see [live_settings docs](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/configuration.html?highlight=live%20settings#disabling-the-live-settings-system)). For example:

  ```
  LIVESETTINGS_OPTIONS = { 1: {
      'DB': False,
      'SETTINGS': { ...
  ```

  ... if you wish and you already know which settings you want to set, you can can set them directly on settings.py too. That's of course a little bit faster. But don't try to hard-code them and if 'DB' is True, change them too on the admin, as probalby the admin-ones would override your hardcoded ones, leading to obscure, buggy situations :-)

  The live-settings relevant for the registration:

  ```
  LIVESETTINGS_OPTIONS = { 1: {
      'DB': False,
      'SETTINGS': {
       ...
          u'SHOP': {
              u'ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION': u'EMAIL',
              u'ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS': u'7',
          ...
          }
      ...
      }
  }}
  ```